# scrapy avoid crawler logging out

Tags: python, scrapy

I am using the scrapy library to facilitate crawling a website.

The website uses authentication and I can successfully login to the page using scrapy.

The page has a URL which will log out the user and destroy the session.

How do I ensure scrapy avoids the logout page when crawling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using [Link Extractors](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html) and simply don't want to follow this particular "logout" link, you can set `deny` property:

```
rules = [Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(deny=[r'logout/']), follow=True),]
```

Another option is to check for `response.url` inside your spider's `parse` method:

```
def parse(self, response):
    if 'logout' in response.url:
        return

    # extract items
```

Hope that helps.